# How define db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA in DB2 on Cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I need some help with my instance of Db2 on Cloud. I need to execute a command for setting DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR. For example I need to define
 **`db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA`**, but I can't do it using IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER or the IBM console.

How can I set it or check that it was already set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The systems are managed. You can [configure Oracle compatibility](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-about) when you [provision the database](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/db2). There is a option switch in the provisioning form:

[image]

That option is not available on the Lite plan because that database is shared.

When you already have provisioned your service instance, you could check some of the values using:

```
select * from sysibmadm.dbcfg
```

See [DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052867.html) for some database configurations set, e.g., number_compat and varchar2_compat. The should be shown as set in the output.

```
select * from sysibmadm.dbcfg where name like '%compat'
```

You can also query environment variables using [ENV_GET_REG_VARIABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0058678.html):

```
select substr(reg_var_value,1,20) as VALUE,
   substr(reg_var_on_disk_value,1,20) as ON_DISK_VALUE
   from table(env_get_reg_variables(-1))
   where reg_var_name = 'DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR'
```

Comment: Thank you very much @data_henrik. I am seeing that option when I try to create a new instance. But, dont exist manner to see that property in my actual instance? I dont sure if I was select that property during the configuration.

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: You can query it..  Look at **ENV_GET_REG_VARIABLES** table function. 
`select MEMBER, substr(REG_VAR_NAME,1,40) var_name, substr(REG_VAR_VALUE,1,30) var_value , substr(REG_VAR_ON_DISK_VALUE, 1, 30) var_on_disk from table(ENV_GET_REG_VARIABLES(-1))`

Comment: I added the example for DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR

Comment: Thank you very much @data_henrik. With the last query, effectively, I can see that property was seeting as ORA.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do...

```
[db2inst1@fergara ~]$ db2set -all
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[i] DB2AUTOSTART=YES
[g] DB2SYSTEM=my.server

[db2inst1@fergara ~]$ db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA

[db2inst1@fergara ~]$ db2set -all
[i] DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[i] DB2AUTOSTART=YES
[g] DB2SYSTEM=my.server
[db2inst1@fergara ~]$
```

Edit: do not forget to stop and start the DB2 server for those to take effect.